# Do I have to dry the blanched and cool-rinsed basil leaves before freezing?

Tags: freezing, drying, basil, blanching

I harvested all my basil today.  I plan to blanch for 3 to 5 seconds and cool quickly with ice water.  (In batches.)  Now what?  Do I really have to spread out the leaves and dry them before freezing?  Sounds tedious!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they are blanched, they will never be as good as fresh.

I'd squish the water out of them and freeze them packed in ice cube trays and store the resulting cubes in ziplock type bags

Comment: So no need to spread them out and dry them (after blanching and cooling)?  That was what all the online instructions said to do but I have a lot of basil to process.  (Summer is over....)

Comment: Okay, the little cubes are all in the freezer now.  Thanks.  I put the cooled leaves in a strainer and then patted dry with a couple paper towels and then stuffed them in the ice cube tray.  Glad that's over.  (I'm allergic to dairy so home-made pesto is a special treat for me.)